# Symfony 3.4: How to validate against an "external" value that's not part of the entity bound to a form

Tags: symfony, validation, symfony-3.4

I'm pretty new to symfony and I'm not yet very experienced with PHP 7.

We have a database of events and *after* an event took place the organizer has to file a report.

`event` and `report` are separate entity classes. 
`report` doesn't know anything about the associated `event`, except its ID.

If a report is filed *before* an event took place validation should fail.
However, I have no idea how to access `event`'s `eventdate` property during validation.

We're defining constraints through annotations and there's already a callback constraint in the `report` entity.

I'm not even sure where to properly do this validation. Directly in the entity class, in the relevant form class or even in the controller?

I have injected the `eventdate` into the form as separate field, but still have no clue how to properly access it for validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be arranged as a two step process - most importantly, link the event via it's ID in the report as a Doctrine association. Reading the ID will read the event that it refers to, and you get the database record - presumably with the date of when the event happened.

```
// in Entity/Report.php
/**
 * One Report has One Event.
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Event")
 * @JoinColumn(name="event_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $event;
```

Here, the database has the `event_id` column, and you get the content of that record from `$report->event` (or a `->getEvent()`).

Then, if your current report callback validation, add another check, to make sure the event has already happened - if not, you add a new violation "you can't make a report on an event that hasn't happened yet."

Comment: Thanks, these annotations were what I needed. Worked swiftly.